# MySQL C#, last x mins from datetime column

Tags: c#, mysql

Using MySQL and I have data being loaded into a table every second. I want to just see the latest x mins (10, 15, whatever I want). Everything I've read says to use INTERVAL and this works in the MySQL query editor BUT I'm querying the table from .NET and the exact same query doesn't seem to work from the .NET driver when using INTERVAL. How can I do this without using the INTERVAL keyword?

Comment: can you post the queryes please?

Comment: bah, nevermind. Asking for the query made me double check and I see what I did wrong. INTERVAL does work with the .NET driver. Sorry

Comment: Are you using the MySQL .net connector? What version? Post an example of your query through C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of nasty, but you can also use ADDTIME() with a negative value:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_col > ADDTIME(NOW(), '-0:5:0');